# Dicord.py how do I take in exactly 3 Members and put them into a variable? It gets MemberNotFound

Tags: python, discord, arguments, discord.py, python-imaging-library

So basically what is happening now is when I pass in the 3 arguments with exact mentions it says all 3 can not be found. I have other commands that use one mention only and those find the users without issue. Here is the error: discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "<@!137608530323701760>  <@!842433014692577332>  <@!235088799074484224>" not found. Here is the code in question:

```
@commands.command()
    async def podium(self, ctx, *, members : discord.Member = None):
        if len(members) == 3:
            i=0
            for member in members:
                member[i] = members
                i += 1


        podiumimg = PIL.Image.open('./cogs/ImageFolder/podium.png')

        size = 350, 350
        mask = PIL.Image.new('L', size, 0)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
        draw.ellipse((0, 0) + size, fill=255)

        pfp1 = member[0].avatar_url
        pfp2 = member[1].avatar_url
        pfp3 = member[2].avatar_url

        img1 = PIL.Image.open(requests.get(pfp1, stream=True).raw)
        img2 = PIL.Image.open(requests.get(pfp2, stream=True).raw)
        img3 = PIL.Image.open(requests.get(pfp3, stream=True).raw)

        pfp1 = img1.resize(size)
        pfp2 = img2.resize(size)
        pfp3 = img3.resize(size)
        mask = mask.resize(size)

        bg_img = podiumimg.copy()
        bg_img.paste(pfp1, (280, 76), mask)
```

Comment: hi, interesting, this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862360/discord-py-membernotfound-exception-when-passing-a-real-member

Comment: @jspcal that won't work the reason it was fixed doesn't apply here

Comment: I don't know anything about Discord, but your for-loop looks odd to me.
Are members objects indexable, and you want each member to have the other member in them, and at different indexes?

Comment: @Anders The purpose of that is to establish an array from the arguments passed in through discord. So then they can be addressed to grab the profile pictures and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is passing all three members as one member. Try moving the asterisk onto `members`

```
@commands.command()
async def podium(self, ctx, *members : discord.Member = None):
```

This should return a list of the member objects that were mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped.